# Editing the Format and Color of a Excel Line Chart with Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a Macro in Excel that could help me to change the color and format of the lines in a chart and the marks on the line. Here is what I want to realize: a 3x3 chart in the Excel, each row is for the color of the Line, the frame color of the marks on the line, and the filling's color of the marks of the line.

I can change the colors and the other things of a line in a line chart now. However, I have met problems with the marks. I can't change the right colors, and the filling's color is always not the color I want. Here's my code, I have put the 3x3 chart of the RGB value from Q10 to S12.

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Cells(10, 17).Value, Cells(10, 18).Value, Cells(10, 19).Value)
        .Weight = xlThin
        .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(Cells(11, 17).Value, Cells(11, 18).Value, Cells(11, 19).Value)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I may made a mistake here for using BackColor instead of ForeColor. After correcting it, this Macro also works with the colors of the chart, and it works fine. But it will just not do what I wanted at first. The filling color of the marks is always blue no matter how I change the figures in the 3x3 chart.

Comment: Would be useful to update your code with the "corrected" version, and maybe a screenshot of the "as-is" and "to-be" for your chart, to illustrate the changes you want to make.